# I want my program to stop taking input if it gets three consecutive zeros and print an error message. don't understand how to implement the condition

Tags: python, input

I want my program to stop taking input if it gets three consecutive zeros and print an error message. don't understand how to implement the condition.here is the code

```py
          
def main():
    number_list=[]
    n = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        item = float(input(f"Enter day {i} running length: "))
  

        number_list.append(item)

        average= sum(number_list)/len(number_list)
        average = float("{:.2f}".format(average))
        if(average < 3):
            print("Your running mean of ", average, " km was too low! ")
        if ( average >= 3):
           print("You were persistent runner! With a mean", average, " km.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This question is confusing.  The title asks about printing the question and input on the same line, but the first sentence asks about consecutive zero inputs.  Which is it?

Comment: I am sorry my title was wrong and I edit it out.

Answer (score 1):

Check if last three element of the `number_list` are all zeroes and then break the loop:

```py
def main():
    number_list = []
    n = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        item = float(input(f"Enter day {i} running length: "))

        number_list.append(item)

        average = sum(number_list) / len(number_list)
        average = float("{:.2f}".format(average))
        if average < 3:
            print("Your running mean of ", average, " km was too low! ")
        if average >= 3:
            print("You were persistent runner! With a mean", average, " km.")

        if number_list[-3:] == [0, 0, 0]:
            print("Last three running lengths were all zeroes, exiting...")
            break
```

Comment: it does not work!

Comment: @NIlim "does not work" doesn't tell us much.  Instead, you should say what this code _does_, and how that's different from what you _wanted_.

Comment: @Szabolcs code works for me. What exactly is not working, @NIlim?

Comment: @JohnGordon does not print anything

Comment: @NIlim This code works for me.  What are you entering for the inputs?

Comment: @JohnGordon does not print anything at all! it does not been ask for inputs at the first place!

Comment: Is there anyways if I can check for the floating zeros also like 0.0,0.00 ??

Comment: @NIlim This code defines a `main()` function but never calls it.  You have to keep the lines from the bottom of your original program that run `main()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, I did not add that! thank you

Comment: @NIlim 0 is equal to 0.0 in Python, so this code should work for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, it sounds like you need it to stop listening for input after the user has input 000, so I would use an if statement

```
n = input("Enter the number of days: ")

if n == '000':
    #what you want it to do

else:
    n = int(n)
```

Comment: `n` is an integer, which will never equal the string `'000'`.

Comment: Also, I suspect "three consecutive zeroes" is intended to mean an answer of zero on three consecutive _questions_.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, when asking for running length for three days, if the input is zero for three days, it will not take anymore input and say you are lazy