# How to stop the loop properly in task

Tags: python

I have the task which is slightly similar to previous case [I want my program to stop taking input if it gets three consecutive zeros and print an error message. don't understand how to implement the condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273964/i-want-my-program-to-stop-taking-input-if-it-gets-three-consecutive-zeros-and-pr).

However, decision there is provided based on list construction which I am not allowed to use in my case.

Original task:

> User was asked to input number of days, for all days user inputs the distance. if average distance less than 3 km then print particular output, if more than 3 km then print another output. But, If we have 3 consecutive days with zero distances provided, **loop must be stopped** with only **print("You had too many consecutive lazy days!")** and without any other further outputs.

I have done some code below but it is wrong because I could not stop the loop properly and link with other conditions.

```
def main():
    days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
    length = ""
    day = 1
    counter = 0
    sum = 0

    while day < days+1:

        length = float(input(f"Enter day {day} running length: "))
        day += 1
        sum += length

        if length == 0: #condition for 3 consecutive
            counter += 1 #counter of input with zero points
            if counter >= 3:
                print("You had too many consecutive lazy days!")
                break

    if (float(sum/days)) < 3:
        print()
        print(f"Your running mean of {round(sum/days,2)} km was too low!")
    else:
        print()
        print(f"You were persistent runner! With a mean of {round(sum/days,2)} km.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Expectation:

```
Enter the number of days: 10
Enter day 1 running length: 3.3
Enter day 2 running length: 1.2
Enter day 3 running length: 4.2
Enter day 4 running length: 0
Enter day 5 running length: 0
Enter day 6 running length: 0

You had too many consecutive lazy days!
```

Comment: What's the actual output instead of the expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super easy fix!

Instead of `break`, use `return`.

```py
if counter >= 3:
    print("You had too many consecutive lazy days!")
    return
```

There can also be times when using `return` isn't possible (e.g. if you aren't inside a function or if you have other code in the function that needs to be run afterward). In this case, you'll want to use `while`/`else`:

```py
while day < days + 1:
    length = float(input(f"Enter day {day+1} running length: "))
    day += 1
    sum += length

    if length == 0:  # condition for 3 consecutive
        counter += 1  # counter of input with zero points
        if counter >= 3:
            print("You had too many consecutive lazy days!")
            break
else:
    if (float(sum / days)) < 3:
        print()
        print(f"Your running mean of {round(sum/days,2)} km was too low!")
    else:
        print()
        print(f"You were persistent runner! With a mean of {round(sum/days,2)} km.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another example using a few different techniques, commentary in code.

```py
from statistics import mean


def main():
    min_days = 3
    days = int(input(f"Enter the number of consecutive running days >= {min_days}: "))
    if days < min_days:
        print(f"The number of consecutive days must be >= {min_days}")
        return

    distance_per_day = []
    day = 0

    while day < days:
        day += 1

        distance = float(input(f"Enter day {day}'s running distance: "))
        distance_per_day.append(distance)

        """ 
        * sum is a built-in Python function that takes an iterable and returns
          the sum of all the elements in the iterable.
        * some_list[-3:] is a slice that takes the last 3 elements of the list.
        """
        last_3_days_distance = sum(distance_per_day[-3:])

        if last_3_days_distance <= 0 and len(distance_per_day[-3:]) == 3:
            print("You had too many consecutive lazy days!")
            break

    """
    * mean is a function from the standard statistics package that takes an 
      iterable and returns the mean of all the elements in the iterable.
    """
    average_distance = round(mean(distance_per_day), 2)
    if average_distance < 3:
        print(f"\nYour running mean of {average_distance} km per day is too low!")
    else:
        print(f"\nYou were persistent runner! With a mean of {average_distance} km per day.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset counter to 0 when length is not 0 and use return to end the loop/function:

```
def main():
    days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
    day, total, counter = 1, 0, 0

    while day < days + 1:
        length = float(input(f"Enter day {day} running length: "))
        counter = 0 if length != 0 else counter + 1
        if counter == 3: return print("\nYou had too many consecutive lazy days!")
        day, total = day + 1, total + length

    print(f"\nYour running mean of {total/days:.2f} km was too low!" if total/days < 3 else
          f"\nYou were persistent runner! With a mean of {total/days:.2f} km.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

non-consecutive result:

```
Enter the number of days: 10
Enter day 1 running length: 3.3
Enter day 2 running length: 0
Enter day 3 running length: 1.2
Enter day 4 running length: 0
Enter day 5 running length: 4.2
Enter day 6 running length: 0
Enter day 7 running length: 3.3
Enter day 8 running length: 1.2
Enter day 9 running length: 4.2
Enter day 10 running length: 0

Your running mean of 1.74 km was too low!
```

consecutive result:

```
Enter the number of days: 10
Enter day 1 running length: 3.3
Enter day 2 running length: 1.2
Enter day 3 running length: 4.2
Enter day 4 running length: 0
Enter day 5 running length: 0
Enter day 6 running length: 0

You had too many consecutive lazy days!
```

Comment: What does `length or length` mean?

Comment: `mark  = length or length` is `if length == 0: mark = length`

Comment: And `if length != 0: mark = length` as well?